# "First year" vs. "the first year" in context

Tags: articles, definite-article

Do I have to use *the* before *first year*? In the 14th episode of the 9th season of *the Walking Dead* it was dropped. Here is the context:

> Judith: But she was a bad person.
>
> They all were.
>
> It's why you did what you did.
>
> Michonne: All this time, I thought you didn't remember.
>
> I hoped you didn't.
> And you... You never said anything
>
> after that **first year**.

I don't understand why *the* was omitted there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have "that" acting as a determiner, you don't need an article as well.

> after **that** first year.

Consider as an example:

- Look at the car.
- Look at that car.

Both "the" and "that" in these two examples serve to highlight which particular car you mean.